# Scripts in the package.json file are failing to run via "npm run" command. Node V 12.18.0

Tags: npm, node-sass

Scripts in the package.json file are failing to run via "npm run" command but it fails with the message "Singh\Template\node_modules.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"
Images attached displays the full error message.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "singh-and-singh-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Demo Template for Singh and Singh Pharmacy",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass scss/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "live": "live-server"
  },
  "author": "Bodhisatwa Barma",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  }
}
```

**Error running live-server**

```
    npm run live

> singh-and-singh-template@1.0.0 live D:\Projects\Singh & Singh\Template
> live-server

'Singh\Template\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal 
or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Projects\live-server\live-server.js'   
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27) 
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! singh-and-singh-template@1.0.0 live: `live-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the singh-and-singh-template@1.0.0 live script.   
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-12T08_12_38_144Z-debug.log
```

**Error running node-sass**

```
    npm run compile:sass

> singh-and-singh-template@1.0.0 compile:sass D:\Projects\Singh & Singh\Template
> node-sass scss/main.scss css/style.css -w

'Singh\Template\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Projects\node-sass\bin\node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! singh-and-singh-template@1.0.0 compile:sass: `node-sass scss/main.scss css/style.css -w`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the singh-and-singh-template@1.0.0 compile:sass script.   
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-12T07_16_57_964Z-debug.log
```

Comment: are you using laravel-mix?

Comment: no just simple html, css and js files. using node-sass package to compile scss into css and live-server package to make a http development server. Was working before but not none of the scripts work. Please help.

Comment: There's a similar problem described in this issue: https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/312

Comment: I already did install it using "npm i live-server --save-dev" to my project not locally. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its seems that npm is trying to look for the package in some other directory rather than node_modules. The same problem is occurring with any package i install. Please help.